# What topics are necessary to log for creating a SLAM comparison bag file?

Tags: slam, localization, navigation, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to collect a bag file to compare different SLAM algorithms and parameters on my mobile base.  What topics should I record?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9235/what-topics-are-necessary-to-log-for-creating-a-slam-comparison-bag-file?/) by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-28

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For gmapping or karto, you need transform data and laser scan data.  So you should record /tf and the topic with your laser data, which is often /scan.  Note that the laser scans should be from a fixed, horizontally mounted laser.  On some robots (e.g., the PR2), this data is on the topic /base_scan.

It's easier if you don't run a SLAM or localization system (or anything else that estimates the map->odom transform) while you record the data.  Otherwise you'll have to filter out that data from the bag (how to do that is another question).

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-02-28**:
There is also this tutorial that covers the full process: http://www.ros.org/wiki/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData#record